# Handle WebPack CSS imports when testing with Mocha

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, webpack

With WebPack you can import styles in your code like this: `import './PageSpinner.styl';` But when you try to test this code with Mocha, your tests will be crashed with SyntaxError because engine tries to handle styles like JS code.

How can I test code like this with Mocha?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had the same problem lately and the solution was through Mocha compilers.

create a file, let's call it 'css-null-compiler.js' and it has:

```
function noop() {
  return null;
}

require.extensions['.styl'] = noop;
// you can add whatever you wanna handle
require.extensions['.scss'] = noop;
require.extensions['.png'] = noop;
// ..etc
```

when you run mocha from the command line, pass this file as a compiler

```
mocha /your/test.spec.js --compilers css:css-null-compiler.js
```

Comment: Cool! You save my life.

Comment: It seems this no longer fixes the issue as `require.extensions['...']` has been deprecated.

@brent fixed this issue for me below.

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with the [ignore-styles](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ignore-styles) package.

Install the package and then require when running mocha.

e.g.

```
mocha --require babel-register --require ignore-styles
```