# Cannot import SCSS file while running mocha test on isomorphic app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mocha.js, webpack

I'm trying to test a react component.

Foo.jsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
require('css/foo'); // foo.scss but using resolve in the webpack

...rest of code
```

Foo.spec.js (this is just a boiler place for test)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as TestUtils from 'react-addons-test-utils';
import Foo from '../src/js/Foo';

function setup() {
  const renderer = TestUtils.createRenderer();
  renderer.render(<Menu />);
  const output = renderer.getRenderOutput();

  return {
    props: props,
    output: output,
    renderer: renderer
  }
}

describe('Menu Component', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    setup();
  })
});
```

tests.js

```
function noop() {
  return null;
}

require.extensions['.scss'] = noop;
```

When trying to load mocha from CLI

```
./node_modules/.bin/mocha tests.js ./test/**/*.spec.js
```

And I'm getting an error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'css/foo' ...
```

I tried:
[Handle WebPack CSS imports when testing with Mocha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683440/handle-webpack-css-imports-when-testing-with-mocha?answertab=votes#tab-top)

but it doesn't work either.

If I comment that line out, the test is executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution.
https://github.com/darul75/web-react/blob/master/app/components/TodoSection/TodoItem.js#L13

When I'm running test on the server:

```
APP_ENV=SERVER ./node_modules/.bin/mocha tests.js ./test/**/*.spec.js
```

On the client I have to add a plugin to the webpack config:

```
plugins: [
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
    'process.env': {
      'APP_ENV': JSON.stringify('BROWSER'),
     }
  })
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Webpack for the test, you can use Sokra (the creator of Webpack)'s null-loader, to make sure that all SCSS requires/imports result in null, and thereby not causing any errors.

```
 {test: /\.scss?$/, loader: 'null'}
```

https://github.com/webpack/null-loader

Comment: I'm using webpack but only for test on the client site with karma, so this would work. But I have 'universal' app and tests for server I'm running from the command line like described above.