# Unit Testing Syntax error, react, mocha

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mocha.js, chai

I'm attempting to set up some tests for my react app with enzyme, mocha and chai. (I'm also using webpack). I have Karma set up for my in-browser tests but i'd like to run these tests with just node.

I'm currently getting a syntax error when it tries to run the test. I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Update: I am running my tests with es6 `mocha 'components/**/*.test.js' --recursive --compilers js:babel-register`

The error I get is:

```
   8 | describe('<button />', () => {
   9 |     it('renders something', () => {
> 10 |         const wrapper = shallow(<button />)
  11 |         expect(wrapper).to.be.present
  12 | })
```

Comment: Are you running the tests with ES6? Something like `mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register` ?

Comment: Yea using `./node_modules/.bin/mocha 'components/**/*.test.js' --recursive --compilers js:babel-register`

Comment: @Ash what's your Babel configuration?

Comment: @robertklep oh I don't think I have anything specifically configured..what do I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up Babel before it can handle JSX syntax.

There are two options: add the configuration to your `package.json`, or create a file called `.babelrc` that contains the configuration.

First, install `babel-preset-react`:

```
$ npm i babel-preset-react --save
```

Next, add the following to your `package.json`:

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [ "react" ]
}
```

(or add that object, without the *"babel"* key, to `.babelrc`)

Another preset that you may likely want to use is `babel-preset-es2015`, which you can add in a similar fashion (just add it to the `presets` array).

More documentation on Babel configuration [here](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/babelrc/) and [here](http://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/) (specifically for `es2015`).

Comment: That solved that problem thank you very much! Though now I have the issue where it's hitting my imported sass file and throwing a syntax error.

Comment: @Ash ah yeah, that's because of your use of Webpack, no doubt. Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32683440/handle-webpack-css-imports-when-testing-with-mocha) can help you with that.

Comment: Solved that styles issue by included ignore-styles and requiring that in my config! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I think `ignore-styles` is actually a better solution :)

Comment: Well i'll certainly take your advice. Would there likely be a situation where I need the styles in the tests?

Comment: @Ash I doubt it. Having the ability to "require" styles is a bit of a hack IMO anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your help @robertklep saved my ass!